# Как в Activity, запущенной startActivityForResult получить requestCode

Tags: android, java

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть некая активити - набор закладок, которую возможно использовать в двух местах приложения. В первом случае нужны все закладки, а во втором, одну надо скрыть. Запускаю через `startActivityForResult`.
Можно ли как-то вытащить `requestCode` в запущенной `activity`, чтобы, анализируя его, скрывать закладку. Не хочется городить городушки с передачей доп-параметра и т.п. Ведь можно в одном случае указать один `requestCode`, в другом - другой.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучший способ - это всё-таки в Intent добавить отдельно параметр.

Comment: да это понятно, что проще добавить. но ведь дублирование, блин...
параметр, код вызова - никакой оптимизации :(
ну и интересно, как добраться до кода вызова. ведь он есть и странно, если его нельзя заполучить в вызванной Activity, весьма странно...

Comment: параметр в intent - самое оно. Завтра выясниться, что requestCode будет ещё один и придется городить в воспомогательной активити ещё логики, которая там абсолютно не нужна.

Comment: Ну как бы может у меня такой случай, что даже если появляются новые requestCode, то они как и предыдущие являются самодастаточными параметрами для того чтобы ими можно было бы рулить в вызванной активити - скрывать ту или иную закладку. в любом случае я вызываю дочернюю активити с разными requestCode. такая вот она универсальная. :) Возвращает по сути одно и тоже, а суть в том, чтобы по разным таблицам распихивать возвращенные значения - в зависимости от requestCode. Вот и всё.
Печально, что их там нельзя получать и придётся пихать дублёров в Extras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что никак. По сути вызов `startActivityForResult` это асинхронный вызов как бы метода, а `requestCode` это возвращаемое значение как бы метода, то есть до окончания вызова узнать возвращаемое значение невозможно.

Неужели сложно добавить при вызове одну строчечку:

```
  intent.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", requestCode);
```

А в самой `Activity` при запуске проверить:

```
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
    requestCode = extras.getInt("REQUEST_CODE");
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. это всё конечно хорошо и понятно. но дублирование данных. печально что нельзя вытащить непосредственно requestCode ведь он, собака такая :), в любом случае существует! Почему так сделано, в чём "гениальность" задумки - в невозможности получить этот код в дочернем активити? ну был бы он приватным, возвращался через вызов какого-нибудь метода, без возможности поменять и всё! :)
ну да ладно, как есть так есть :(

Comment: Я однажды озадачился этим, и не нашел, тоже решил что никак. Мы его получаем назад в том методе, где вызывали, чтобы различать ответы асинхронных запросов. А в вызванном активити его, похоже, не достать. Остается только экстра ((